# How to get Rhythmbox working on mp3

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox, music-player

Click on an mp3 file that used to work, rhythmbox comes up and appears to be playing, but no audio comes from speakers or headphone jack.  Jumping forward on song sometimes produces a very brief spurt of the song.  Other players play the file if brought up in 'open with', e.g., movie player.  Sound on computers is otherwise normal.

The problem exists on two Toshiba Satellite laptops, one a 32 bit CPU and the other a 64 bit machine.  Both have clean Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit installs with restricted extras and medibuntu.  Not sure if Rhythmbox worked before the restricted extras and medibuntu were installed.

apt-get update and apt-get upgrade made no difference.

Internet search reveals only one other user reporting similar problem.  Before I back it all up and reinstall 12.04 over again is there something else i should do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Since 11.10 I have seen no need to have medibuntu since basically all formats are in the package "Ubuntu Restricted Extras". At least in the common videos and music formats. In your case, the mp3 format.

What I would do is remove the medibuntu ppa. Then go to Software Center and look for **restricted**

You should see a package called "Ubuntu Restricted Extras". Install this package (Or Reinstall it if you did already) and after it is installed you should have support for mp3 files. You will be able to listen to them.

For me it is working here and on 3 other PCs.

The only thing needed is the Restricted Extras package.

I would also like to point out, just in case somebody asks why remove the medibuntu ppa. I had a problem similar to the MP3 mentioned here. The problem was a somewhat confusion between the Restricted Extras and the Medibuntu packages. Somehow there was a format war between them. It was solved by removing medibuntu and just using what Ubuntu has. In this case the restricted one.